Firestore (10.13.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x45406b55 transport errored
Few days ago, my porfolio was working fine. But after I cloned it from my Github repo and started project has this problem:
[2024-09-07T07:30:14.547Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.13.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x45406b55 transport errored.
I use ReactJS for front-end and Firebase for backend. I hope that someone can help me to solve this problem? I tried some ways but it didn't work.
Link to my repository: https://github.com/1902VanHuongCoder/Paul-To-Portfolio-2024
I tried to add this code to my firebase config but it didn't work:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = { 
  apiKey : import.meta.env.VITE_apiKey, 
  authDomain : import.meta.env.VITE_authDomain, 
  projectId : import.meta.env.VITE_projectId, 
  storageBucket : import.meta.env.VITE_storageBucket, 
  messagingSenderId : import.meta.env.VITE_messagingSenderId, 
  appId : import.meta.env.VITE_appId,
};


// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true
  })
 
// export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);

